# Sql user shows up in my logs, but it's not in user table nor do I have ''@localhost either

Tags: mysql, security

I think I'm asking a question I know the answer to, but I want to be 100% before I panic.

My SQL logs are showing the following regarding a user I've never seen before

```
Access denied for user 'random username showing here'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

but this user is nowhere to be found anywhere in my user table, and I checked for a ''@localhost and from what I can tell so far I don't have an anonymous user.

What does this mean? I'm a little confused and not sure if my system has been comped...

I searched through both my server users which are only 2 and then search through mysql users and found nothing that matches, I also did a query for an anonymous user, an got nothing back.

Comment: Of course it's not in your user table, that's why it's being denied. Someone is trying to break into your MySQL server random usernames.

Comment: And since it's coming from `localhost`, it means they've already broken into your server.

Comment: @Barmar Ahh I see thank you for clearing up my confusion!